# Show editor and output at the same time

Tags: octave

When using the octave-IDE, I can select between the command window and the editor, but not see both at the same time.
Therefore I can't immediatly see outputs from print statements in my scripts.

Is there a layout that shows both or am I doing something else wrong?

Comment: Strange, I can see both. Check if Window->Show command window and Window->Show editor are both checked.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can drag any window and reposition it within the layout.

E.g., if you switch to the Editor window and click and drag with your mouse the editor's titlebar (i.e. the bit that says 'Editor', right about the editor's File / View menu), you can then start dragging it to the right, and identify a new 'grid' cell to drop it in.

[image]

[image]

If you're not getting an appropriate gridpoint to drop it in, try resetting the layout and trying again (from Window tab, select "Reset Default Window Layout" at the bottom)

Comment: just to add, there is also a small icon in the upper left of the tabs (to the left of the 'x' that will close it) that will 'undock' the editor into it's own separate window that can then be positioned however you like

Comment: @NickJ yes, or similarly you can double-click to detach. Thanks for the comment!

Comment: huh.  I never knew that. learn something new every day.

Comment: I was clicking and dragging the tab at the *bottom* of the pane that says "Editor". I didn't notice the clickable title bar at the *top* of the pane. Thanks for showing!

Comment: Could this be the case that this method only works in linux? I'm using windows 10 with Octave 6.4.0 and I'm unable to identify a new 'grid' cell to drop it in.

Comment: @Dabed Hi Dabed. I'm not on windows now to test, but that's highly unlikely. Did you read the last sentence in the answer about resetting if the grid doesn't appear? Does that not work either? If not, I would open a bug on the octave bug tracker and see what people say there.

Comment: Thanks, I tried resetting the grid too but no difference, I may open a bug on the octave tracker if I ever test it too on a linux system but I don't see this happening so I think I will just live with this issue =) Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

was having a similar issue to the question.
cmd window and editor were on tabs and could undock be could not reporition in separate windows. noticed octave app was not maximized, once i maximized app, i could then position them as desired

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).